# a Magento custom page is always forced to use https, why?

Tags: magento, url, https

Normally in  Magento only checkout and customer account page use https. I installed a custom module for store locator and i don't know why it is always opened in https. Because of that those js, css.. are blocked because of mixed content.

Other pages like catalog are still ok in http. 
When i look at this module etc/config.xml file, under frontend , i don't find any secure_url xml tag.
What decides a page should be secure or not in Magento? How can i force the system to use unsecure url for my module controller?

thank you

UPDATE: i decided to use another extension from community and it works without https. It is Dotsquares StoreLocator module.

Answer (score 1):

In module Config.xml you need to remove `secure_url` tag.

```
<frontend>
   <secure_url>  // you need to remove this
      <storelocator>/storelocator/index</storelocator> // this may be something else
   </secure_url>
</frontend>
```

Hope this will work !!

Comment: Thank you but i mentioned in my question that i look in config.xml file and see no secure_url tag at all. Strange right?

Comment: sorry. didn't notice that. Which extension you are using, please let me know the url if it is free. I will check

Comment: yes, it is free. it was this one my friend http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-map-store-locator.html

Answer (score -1):

have you change both secure and insecure base URLS in magento to use https?

removing the entry in the core_config_data table will allow the site from both.

Comment: no, i didn't do that. I use https for secure and http for unsecured. I gave up and use another extension for store locator now. Thanks everybody for your time